# Too many first chance exceptions in Visual Studio 2013 project using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am using WCF in my project. The project was working fine before. Suddenly it has started throwing errors. I can build the project successfully but when I run it, a lot of first chance exceptions are being thrown. Most of them are related to microlib.dll.

A few AccessViolationException in System.Web.dll and WcfSvcHost.exe are also being thrown.

All other visual studio solutions are working fine except this one.

1. I have tried running the project in both Debug and release mode.
2. I have tried deleting IISExpress folder in Documents Directory
3. My VS solution contains many class liberaries and all are running in Any CPU configuration.

I cannot figure out the reason what is causing the issue. I checked the microlib.dll in C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/assembly and saw it is last modified in January.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: are you under source control?

Comment: yes, using Team Foundation server

Comment: so can you get some older version and find the one without any problem?

Comment: I have tried this option.. Also configured the solution on another machine. But still the issue persist.

Comment: do you have sample project to share and let us debug?

Comment: Unfortunately No :( I cannot share the code and do not have any sample project for the same